# "TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined" in vscode

Tags: javascript, discord.js

```
D:\GG\PanCakeBot\index.js:18
            bot.commands.set(props.help.name, props)
                                        ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
    at D:\GG\PanCakeBot\index.js:18:41
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at D:\GG\PanCakeBot\index.js:16:16
    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:171:23)
```

^ That is an error when I am trying to run the discord bot with this command in vscode.

```
fs.readdir('./commands', (err, files) => {
        if(err) return console.log(err);
        let jsfile = files.filter(f => f.split(".").pop() == 'js');

        if(jsfile.length == 0) {return console.log("Could not find any commands!")}

        jsfile.forEach(f => {
            let props = require(./commands/${f});
            bot.commands.set(props.help.name, props)
        })
```

What did I miss there and how to fix it?

Comment: It means that `props.help` is `undefined` when the line is executed.

Comment: console props and check because props.help is undefined

Answer (score 0):

`props.help` is undefined, so reading `props.help.name` results in an error. `console.log()` yor `jsflile`, `f`, and `props` to see what's wrong.